# CSS for sorted cols not applied in zebra-striped datatables

Tags: css, datatables

see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7QtSS/

When checking with Firefox 's inspector which styles are applied the first cell (top left, below title), it uses the style for`tr.odd td.sorting_1` from demo_tables[368] which is overwritten by the style for `tr.odd td.dc1´in inline[23].

I was expecting my more specific style for `tr.odd td.dc1 td.sorting_1` from inline[8] would be applied instead, but it is not - even when changing the order of these styles (as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7rezt/1/) - so where is my fault, how can I assign a different color to sorted columns?

Comment: You shouldn't be applying your own `odd`/`even` classes to your rows. Use the the CSSS pseudo classes [`:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Thanks @RoToRa, that works as well :) What is the reasoning behind this? Not to rely on naming-conventions?

Comment: The reasoning is that it's better to have the browser do something automatically instead of you doing it manually - especially since it's independent of the sorting of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select based on multiple classes, these need to be written directly after each another – with no white space. So it should be:

`tr.odd td.dc1.sorting_1 {
   blabla
}`

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is incorrect CSS-syntax. `tr.odd td.dc1 td.sorting_1` would mean

set `background-color` for `sorting_1`, when `sorting_1` is a child of `dc1` and `dc1` is a child of `odd`.

You probably want to set both `td.dc1` *and* `td.sorting_1` to `background-color: #e55c5c;` when they are child of `tr.odd` :

```css
tr.odd td.dc1, tr.odd td.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #e55c5c;
}
```

---

The whole CSS :

```css
tr.odd td.dc1, tr.odd td.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #e55c5c;
}
tr.even td.dc1, tr.even td.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f05b5b;
}
tr.odd td.dc1 {
    background-color: #e86e6e;
}
tr.even td.dc1 {
    background-color: #f37878;
}
tr.odd td.dc1, tr.odd td.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #e55c5c;
}
tr.even td.dc1, tr.even td.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f05b5b;
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/H95TC/**

Comment: Thank you - you named the error ("wrong css-selector"), but made the wrong assumption about what I wanted to achieve. But your post help to get it sorted out - thanks very much! (I've upvoted your post)

Comment: @MBaas OK. Upvoted your question as well. But cannot quite get your solution below to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/QuuHj/ (using chrome / ubuntu)

Comment: Updated your example. The declaration for tr.odd td.dc1.sorting_1/tr.even td.dc1.sorting_1 was given twice in the CSS... Have changed colours to make the difference more visible.